# Multi-threaded small app and logging

Tags: c#, multithreading, logging

I have here a small question.
I wrote a small multi threaded app which doesnt do much, it just connects to some resource, 
reades few fields writes them to log and that is it.
What i would love to know if everything is being logged or not.
Here is the code for logging:

```
private TextWriter textWriter;
private TextWriter errorWriter;

public Logger(string filePath, string errorLogFile)
{
    textWriter = TextWriter.Synchronized(File.AppendText(filePath));
    errorWriter = TextWriter.Synchronized(File.AppendText(errorLogFile));
}

public void WriteToLog(string text)
{
    textWriter.WriteLine(text);
}
    ...
```

So when let say i have 100 threads will this manage all data being written to log or will it skip some threads?
I will create an instance of logger in main and pass it to executor:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < threadNumber; i++)
        {
            Executor executor = new Executor(logger)
        }
```

Comment: Consider using an existing logging library instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I suggest [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No skipping does occur. Your code is thread safe.**
You are using `TextWriter.Synchronized` to create a thread safe wrapper for writing to your file. The synchronized `TextWriter` is implemented using the `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]`  attribute which basically is the same as doing a lock on the instance this method is contained in.
That being said, the locking that happens causes all other threads to wait until the one thread that is currently writing is finished doing so.
A better approach would be to create a class that contains a [thread safe non-blocking queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) where you put your log entries to and one thread that processes them and puts them into the log file. If a lot of logging is going on in your application that will most likely increase the performance.

Comment: To increase the effect. Blocking all other threads when writing to a queue is better than blocking all other threads when writing to a file, but it *still* blocks all other threads.

Comment: 'non-blocking', to me, means that that the single logger thread has to resort to polling to see if there are any new entries to write to the file, but I can see what you're getting at, (though I would not expect much contention anyway as long as each producer thread only pushes an object reference).  I guess that a non-blocking ConcurrentQueue with a semaphore, (or some other signaling mechanism), for the log-write thread to wait on would work fine.

Comment: I agree that it wouldn't make much difference. But as there already is a non-blocking thread safe queue in .NET 4, why not use it? I would implement the LogFileWriter using a timer that doesn't auto reset. When the timer elapses, all entries from the queue are written to the log file and afterwards the timer is started again.

Comment: Fine. Upside - the efficiency of the log writer may be higher if more than one log entry is written at once when the timer fires.  Downside - the increased latency of log writing and CPU waste of continually firing up the logger thread if there are often no log entries to write.

Comment: @MartinJames: Sure, you need to find a compromise here.